# How to add custom variables in haxe templates?

Tags: templates, haxe, openfl

Haxe takes some templates to `bin` folder when it compiles. It process templates, replacing variables in it `::WIN_WIDTH::` with values `640`. It can also take your custom templates like so:

```
<template path="your/template.txt" rename="tmpl.txt"/>
```

I would like to know is there any way to place your own variables `::myvar::` in those templates?

**EDIT**
http://old.haxe.org/doc/cross/template - Unfortunately, that article only explains how to execute `haxe.Template` class instances. In the end you will get the string (your processed template).

What I want is to add my custom placeholders to default haxe templates, such as OpenFL Android project templates. I need Haxe to process it's templates WITH my own placeholders and outputs it in the `bin` folder, as usually does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to figure it out the hard way, but it turns out that the <setenv> tag really works as advertised.

In project.xml:

```
<setenv name="MY_VAR" value="612" />
```

In template.txt:

```
::if ENV_MY_VAR::
    The value of MY_VAR is ::ENV_MY_VAR::.
::else::
    MY_VAR is not defined.
::end::
```

You could also define it as "myvar", but then you'd have to use "ENV_myvar" in template.txt.

Answer (score 0):

http://old.haxe.org/doc/cross/template
this explain everything about templates, how to use variables and things like if and foreach.

Comment: Rafael Oliveira, I expected such answers. Sorry if I'm not clear, I updated my question.